# Vector iterators incompatible: DEBUG

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, iterator, rogue-wave

Why is this piece of code giving me the error : Vector iterators incompatible

This piece of code was traced back to the Rogue Wave file tpordvec.h

```
    std::vector<T*> v;
    const T* a  // Where T is a template Class 
    for (std::vector<T*>::iterator p = v.begin(); p != v.end(); p++)
    {
        if (**p == *a)
        {
            T* temp = *p;
            if ( v.erase(p) == v.end()) //ASSERTION ERROR HERE
               return NULL;

            return temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

> Iterators and references to the erased elements and to the elements between them and the end of the container are invalidated. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

Hence if the `vector.end()` is evaluated before the `vector.erase()` and `vector.erase()` really erases and by doing so invalidates the iterators till `end()`, the call to `operator==()` will be between two incompatible iterators.

Something like this would be better:

```
auto it = v.erase(p); 
if ( it == v.end())
{ 
       return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Ah!  Yes, slightly counter-intuitively in the original code `end()` is called first (according to my debugger) and then the `erase()` invalidates the iterator that `end()` returned.